# How to add a category and category path to Magento programatically?

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to export categories from one magento store and import to another one.

The following information is part of categories which must to inserted in store.

```
Default Category    2
All Categories  2/30
Electronics 2/30/12
TV & Video  2/30/12/13
```

I try this following script to import one category but doesn't work. The script doesn't import the category.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default'); // Default or your store view name.

//get a new category object
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setStoreId(0); // 0 = default/all store view. If you want to save data for a specific store view, replace 0 by Mage::app()->getStore()->getId().

//if update
if ($id) {
  $category->load($id);
}

$general['name'] = "All Categories";
$general['path'] = "2/30"; // catalog path
$general['description'] = "";
$general['meta_title'] = ""; //Page title
$general['meta_keywords'] = "";
$general['meta_description'] = "";
$general['landing_page'] = ""; //has to be created in advance, here comes id
$general['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE"; //static block and the products are shown on the page
$general['is_active'] = 1;
$general['is_anchor'] = 0;
$general['page_layout'] = 'two_columns_left';

$category->addData($general);

try {
    $category->save();
    echo "Success! Id: ".$category->getId();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Which error you are facing right now ?

Comment: The category didn't insert and script was completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your exact code and tested it. As you sad, script is sucessfull but no category in magento backend ... but there is one in the database, just check the table **catalog_category_entity**.

The problem is, you pass the wrong **path** property. The top category is allways ID=1. When, after installation, you create your catalogs top category, it will be something greater then 1. In my case it is ID=3.

So to order the new category below the root category I created (ID=3), I must set the value **1/3** for **path**

```
$general['path'] = "1/3"; // catalog path
```

In your case I gues it should work with the following value

```
$general['path'] = "1/2/30"; // catalog path
```